# codename one augmented reality

Tags: augmented-reality, codenameone

I'd like to port a small android app which uses camera and draws some infos on the screen while pointing at a specific location. My intention is to port it on iOS. I've found that codename one could be suitable but I don't know if it supports the use of the camera. Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Codename One still doesn't support some of the more elaborate AR API's introduced by Google/Apple but we do support placing a camera view finder into your app with a new cn1lib: https://github.com/codenameone/CameraKitCodenameOne

Original answer below for reference:

It supports the use of the camera but currently doesn't support AR use cases where you draw on the camera viewfinder. You can do that with [native code support](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) but since I understand that this is the main feature of the app its probably not the ideal solution.

If its just a small feature within a large app then native interfaces make sense.